# How can I use React context to get the router exactly and only where I need it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react

I've built a [minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkxv2951rv) demonstrating the problem. In short, if I want to use the router in a component, e.g. because it has `Route`s nested within it, then I need to drill the router props, using `withRouter`, through every ancestor of that component, even if those ancestors don't use the router themselves.

I think it is related to [issue #6072](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6072), but it is marked fixed. I've read the "Dealing with Update Blocking" document in react-router.

Why is this necessary? It means that I need to conservatively add `withRouter` to every component because I can't predict, in general, which ones will have descendants that need the router. I thought the point of context in React was to relieve me from this, so that I could pull out the router exactly where it's needed, and forget about it everywhere in-between. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: I made some components that appear to do what I want. Anything wrong with this solution? Does it already exist in a library somewhere? https://codesandbox.io/s/lx2o75jwmq

Comment: I am not 100% sure since I've never used mobx but when using Redux with React-Router, only the component that is connected to redux and has route system needs to be HOC-ed with `withRouter`. Otherwise the RouteComponentProps will always be passed down and accessible by the children no matter how deep.

Comment: can you provide a code example? I'm 99% sure you're overthinking this. I've made many applications with react-router v4 (react-router-dom) and have NEVER needed to pass props down. using `<Route />` components is all you need, no matter how nested

Comment: I put the example in the question. It's the first link: https://codesandbox.io/s/kkxv2951rv The app is broken unless `IgnoresRouter` has the router props injected with `withRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are hitting this:

> Important Note: withRouter does not subscribe to location changes like React Redux’s connect does for state changes. Instead, re-renders after location changes propagate out from the  component. This means that withRouter does not re-render on route transitions unless its parent component re-renders. If you are using withRouter to prevent updates from being blocked by shouldComponentUpdate, it is important that withRouter wraps the component that implements shouldComponentUpdate.

from: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

So: it will work, if you don't make your "IgnoreRouter" component an `observer`. I've tried it in your codebox.

```
// from this:
let IgnoresRouter = observer(() => (
  <div>
    <h1>IgnoresRouter</h1>
    <UsesRouter />
  </div>
));

// to this:
let IgnoresRouter = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>IgnoresRouter</h1>
    <UsesRouter />
  </div>
);
```

Why: As an observer, ignoresRouter component has no "dependencies" or values to observe, meaning: it won't re-render.

`mobx-react.observer` will implement shouldComponentUpdate for you. (That's why it is easier to have better performance with mobx). But now it's playing against you.

If you remove observer, it will re-render due to the fact that `mobx-react` is **not** controlling the rendering (shouldComponentUpdate) anymore. So, referring to the quote of the docs, now the parent (ignoreRouter) is re-rendering, and thus the child with the `withRouter` can.

Now, since you use mobx, you might want to take a step back for a moment and read [this excellent article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-decouple-state-and-ui-a-k-a-you-dont-need-componentwillmount-cc90b787aa37) from the author of mobx and possibly replace react-router with something arguably better. People have built a router based on these principles: https://github.com/nareshbhatia/mobx-state-router

I can't really tell if it's "awesome" because I haven't used `mobx-state-router` myself, but I made my own custom solution based on the same principles, so in the end, very similar to mobx-state-router and it works like a charm.

Comment: In this demonstrative example, yes, nothing in `IgnoresRouter` uses observable properties, but in my real app, it does. Like I said, I've already read the "Dealing with Update Blocking" document in react-router, which goes over this. I'm just surprised the recommended solution was to wire `withRouter` through everything. It defeats the purpose of context, which I used in my solution that does exactly what I want (and I suspect does what many other people want).

Comment: I've also already read the "You don't need componentWillMount" piece. It is from 2016, before react-router 4, and it uses a static route tree, not what I want.

Comment: You don't really need a static route tree. But it is useful to create one so that you can attach hooks. Since the goal of the pattern there is to avoid componentWillMount / componentWillUnmount to fetch data or implement your use case. If you tie your calls in components hooks, then you can not test your use cases without the UI. That shows that you have coupling between UI and Business logic which isn't a good thing in general, may not be a problem in some situation or cause big troubles in the future. Depends on your situation.